# Why manual autocorrelation does not match acf() results?

Tags: r, autocorrelation

I'm trying to understand acf and pacf. But do not understand why acf() results do not match simple cor() with lag1

I have simulated a time series

```
set.seed(100)
ar_sim <- arima.sim(list(order = c(1,0,0), ar = 0.4), n = 100)

ar_sim_t <- ar_sim[1:99]
ar_sim_t1 <- ar_sim[2:100]

cor(ar_sim_t, ar_sim_t1)   ## 0.1438489
acf(ar_sim)[[1]][2]        ## 0.1432205
```

Could you please explain why the first lag correlation in acf() does not exactly match the manual cor() between the series and lag1?

Comment: Hi, I think your code should be `ar_sim_t <- ar_sim[1:99]` and
`ar_sim_t1 <- ar_sim[2:100]`. The difference remains bu at least it works

Comment: @Chelmy88 sorry, you are correct, I actually did what you said, feel free to check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way of estimating the autocorrelation of a *discrete process with known mean and variance* is the following. See, for instance, the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Estimation).

```
n <- length(ar_sim)
l <- 1
mu <- mean(ar_sim)
s <- sd(ar_sim)

sum((ar_sim_t - mu)*(ar_sim_t1 - mu))/((n - l)*s^2)
#[1] 0.1432205
```

This value is not `identical` to the one computed by the built-in `stats::acf` but is very close to it.

```
a.stats <- acf(ar_sim)[[1]][2]
a.manual <- sum((ar_sim_t - mu)*(ar_sim_t1 - mu))/((n - l)*sd(ar_sim)^2)

all.equal(a.stats, a.manual)  # TRUE
identical(a.stats, a.manual)  # FALSE

a.stats - a.manual
#[1] 1.110223e-16
```

Comment: probably the implemented `cor` function in R divide by n and not n-1

Comment: @Chelmy88 The computation is in a C language function. But maybe not, the difference between what function `stats::acf` computes and the manual computation above is within floating-point accuracy.

Comment: To reproduce the result given by `cor`: `mn0 <- mean(ar_sim_t);
mn1 <- mean(ar_sim_t1);
cov01 <- sum((ar_sim_t-mn0)*(ar_sim_t1-mn1))/(n-2);
cov01/(sd(ar_sim_t)*sd(ar_sim_t1))`

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation @RuiBarradas, but shouldn't cor() output the same value as acf()?

Comment: Remember that in `cor` you are using 2 vector of `n-1` length, hence in `cov01` the denominator is `(n-1)-1`.

Comment: @MarcoSandri Right, sorry for the messy explanation.

Comment: @DonDani No, it shouldn't, they are using different formulas because they are computing different things. See my answer plus these comments: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57522874/why-manual-autocorrelation-does-not-match-acf-results/57523429#comment101513972_57523429) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57522874/why-manual-autocorrelation-does-not-match-acf-results/57523429?noredirect=1#comment101514168_57523429).